# Python - checking all the available functions for pd.DataFrame.groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I know in pandas `pd.DataFrame.groupby` has quite many methods such as sum, mean, head, etc. How do I easily get a list of all the available functions of groupby? I try `dir()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The docs outline this fairly well https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html

Comment: Dir really will list them, but it isn't a very helpful means of learning.  `help(thing)` is often more useful.  But pandas gas extensive docs